# PHP, get web-page content words

Tags: php

I am building a website that recommend other good website.

Therefore, I collected a lot websites by using crawling system.

Now, I am trying to distinguish whether the website has good words or not by using PHP.

```
$page_content = file_get_contents($url);
$bad_word = 'damn';

if(strstr($page_content, $bad_word)):
    $result = 'YES';
else:
    $result = 'NO';
endif;
```

My code is something like this.

I use Codeigniter and get this message.

```
An Error Was Encountered

Unable to load your default controller. Please make sure the controller specified in your Routes.php file is valid.
```

It works fine some website, but it doesn't work for the other website.

Is there other way to retrieve content of the website?

Comment: You need give some do-not-work example to help others find out why.

Comment: Sounds like a SLOW way to do it, if you are checking the words every single time (and one by one).

Comment: i hope you are aware that your "crawler" will most likely mark most of news and social networking sites as "bad".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already answered similar post yesterday but here is goes again:) You can use preg_match() for much better results. The preg_match doesn't encompass regular expressions only. It can do exactly what you need. i.e.:

```
if (preg_match("/bad-word/i", "page written content of many good and bad words")) {
    $result = 'YES';

} else {
     $result = 'NO';

}
```

The "i" means case sensitive, check PHP manual for more examples: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 0):

Some websites need form submits aka via cURL.